# htaccess - internet server error 500 on XAMPP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I am trying to run script on XAMPP but get "internet server error 500".  Its fine when running on the live server.  I assume this is a .htaccess error.  The htaccess code is below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

I have enabled htaccess by uncommenting the line:

> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

in the config file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Extremely likely (I'm positive on that) you have infinite rewrite loop (check your error log for details -- it will tell you exact reason). Your second rewrite rule will rewrite over and over again -- you need to add some condition to prevent further rewriting (to not rewrite already rewritten URLs), e.g. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/`

Comment: the error log states:[Wed Mar 14 11:56:18 2012] [alert] [client ::1] C:/xampp/htdocs/widgets/mobile/mvc/framework/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here

Comment: @LazyOne, I have added the condition but still same error.

Comment: Based on error message: look at `AllowOverride` directive -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride . You will need to add `AllowOverride All` or something like that in your **Apache main config file** (e.g. httpd.conf) -- don't forget to restart Apache after making changes in httpd.conf file (changes are not picked up automatically).

Comment: where resides your .htaccess file? and could you write your folder path?

Answer (score 2):

Try editing this part in your **httpd.conf** and set `AllowOverride All`

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

Or try this:

```
<Directory />
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: AllowOverride All is already set in the config file and I restarted apache, no joy.

Comment: Have changed the htaccess to file include the above and still does not work. Have I added it correctly?<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
 </IfModule>
 
 <Directory />
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>  Thanks

Comment: @LeeTee Please check the manual on RewriteCond directive: that line should go **before** second RewriteRule line. Please check error log again (in case if it has different error this time).

Comment: Ok, Ive changed to be exactly as specified above and get error: [Wed Mar 14 13:42:10 2012] [alert] [client ::1] C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/widgets/mobile/mvc/framework/.htaccess: C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/widgets/mobile/mvc/framework/.htaccess:1: <Directory> was not closed.

Comment: Please read the MANUAL: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory . **Context: server config, virtual host**. The `Directory` directive CANNOT be used in .htaccess.

Comment: Sorry Ive not much experience with htaccess and none of it is making sense.  I've removed "Directory" and am now back to square 1  :0(