# xampp phpmyadmin error code 500 on windows server

Tags: windows, server, phpmyadmin, xampp

i want to change the structure of a table on a database in PhpMyadmin and i get the error:

Error in processing request. Error code 500. Error text: Internal Server Error (rejected). It seems that the connection to the server has been lost. please check your network connectivity and server status.

But i was able to access the database and display the tables.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow rvuro! The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition at prevented it from fulfilling
the request. You need to view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701610/htaccess-internet-server-error-500-on-xampp and solve using editing in httpd.conf file

Comment: That answer link doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question that was asked, since this is about using phpMyAdmin and that link (which was closed without an answer) is about a typo and misconfiguration of the Apache configuration file. I'm not sure how that is related to this question.

Comment: @rvuro, when there is an error 500, it's usually logged by the webserver process. What does the webserver error log show you?

Comment: @isaacBennetch i am using xampp. i checked for log_files executing this query  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log_files%'`  and result shows _innodb_log_files_in_group | 2_

Comment: Oh, sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear - you need to look in your webserver error log. Often this is a file on disk or in the Windows Event Log, I believe the default for XAMPP is in the `apache\logs\error.log` file within your XAMPP folder.

Comment: I wanted to make changes to data type but i found other options using script. However, i will try to find the logs and share. I used IIS to open PhpMyadmin, that may be the issue. I will try to locate the error logs